# React Ssr React-Router

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

Can someone, please, explain - how to create SSR with React Routes V6,
There are a lot of snippets with simple React SSR -  without routes.

Maybe there is any course or lesson about React-SSR and it would be great if there would be SSR with react-routers (react-router-dom, especially V6), or any GitHub repo.

Most problem is `<StaticRoutes>` - i saw documentation but i didn`t get it... :(

Need it for my project - https://github.com/Ivan-Bliminse/movie-b-movie

Comment: Welcome @Ivan Bliminse. This doc could help with React-SSR using react-router v6: https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/guides/ssr.

Comment: Wow, Thank you! 
    But now i got a problem with   : 

import express from "express";
^^^^^^
 import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module // with all imports...

Answer (score 0):

SO DONE !

delete "type" : "module" from package.json, if you dont have it then ok,

in folder 'server' create 1 more file => index.js

index.js

```
require("@babel/register")({
  ignore: [/(node_module)/],
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
});

require("./server");
```

and in package.json

```
"ssr": "node server/index.js"
or
"ssr": "nodemon server/index.js"
```

ofc before all  - install packages

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
```

Answer (score 0):

This doc could help with React-SSR using react-router v6: reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/guides/ssr.